# Apache wicketStuff-GMap Api

Tags: apache, wicket, wicketstuff

How do I feed bunch of addresses to Google map via Wicketstuff GMap api so that when map is launched, I see marker/balloon based on city. Basically I want to be able to feed all the addresses and have map show one balloon/city and  when city balloon is clicked, launch a wicket panel.I am using wicket 1.4.13 and wicketstuff 1.5.16.

Comment: Thanks Martin for the information.
  With wicketstuff GeoCoder and GLatLng  apis  I keep getting org.wicketstuff.gmap.geocoder.GeocoderException: OVER_QUERY_LIMIT  exception , while creating GLatLng  object using GeoCoder.   
  Geocoder coderG = new Geocoder();
  GLatLng gLatLng1 = coderG.geocode("1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA, USA"); 
    
If I hard code lat/lon (GLatLng gLatLng1 = new LatLng(37.4224764,-122.0842499)) , then it's fine.Any idea why Geocoder is not working with address directly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `Marker` objects to the map for each city:

```
 final GMap map = new GMap("wicketId", "yourApiKey");

 GMarkerOptions markerOptions = new GMarkerOptions(map, latLng, "A marker for city Xyz", true);
 map.addOverlay(new GMarker(markerOptions));
```

I'd recommend you to take a look at the [examples](https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/tree/91f62d9b12c198cc8baaa50b309994e2e4f19701/gmap3-parent/gmap3-examples/src/main/java/org/wicketstuff/examples/gmap)

Comment: I figured out that Geocoder.encode api for wicketstuff 15.13 was not appending api_key to the url and hence the error was getting thrown. I modified the URL obtained to include api_key and also changes the protocol to https from http and it worked.